# Changing button text and ID by clicking on it

Tags: android

In part of my program, I change the id and text of a button when it is clicked. When the button is clicked again, the id and text are reverted to the previous values. However, I am getting error. (I have added a comment to the line where I am getting the error).

I just need to change text by clicking a button. Then change it back to the old values by clicking it again. Does anyone have a solution or some better idea on how to accomplish this?

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
      switch(v.getId()){
           case R.id.btn_start_again:
                mPlayer.stop();
                start.setText("Pause");
                start.setId(R.id.pause);
                break;

           case R.id.pause:
               start.setText("Pause");          //here it is not accepting pause
               start.setId(R.id.btn_start_again);
               break; 
       }
  }
```

Comment: Why you are changing id ?

Comment: Why do you have to change the id? Describe your problem with more details there should be another way :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you want to change the `id` of the `Button`. What it looks like you are doing is having a `Button` that starts play then turns to pause while playing. Simply have the two `Buttons` in the same space in your xml. Start with the `visibility` of the pause `Button` as `gone` then check the `visibility` in the function.

Something like

```
public void onClick(View v) {
switch(v.getId()){
case R.id.btn_start_again:
    mPlayer.stop();
    btnPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    btnPlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    break;

case R.id.pause:
    btnPause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btnPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    break; 
}
```

[Button Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to change the ID of the button, use something like a boolean flag to keep track  of the *state* of the button:

```
boolean isPlaying = false;

public void onClick(View v) {
   switch(v.getId()){
       case R.id.btn_start_again:
          if(isPlaying){
              mPlayer.stop();
              start.setText("Play");         
              isPlaying = !isPlaying;
          }else{
              //mPlayer.start() <--- you don't start it anywhere?
              start.setText("Pause");
              isPlaying = !isPlaying;
          }
       break;
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There a better way you can do it.

Set different tag to the button according to the status.

Answer (score 1):

changing ID programmatically is a bad idea, better solution is to define a global boolean value:

```
    private boolean isSelected = false;
```

and then in Your onClick:

```
           public void onClick(View v) {

               if(isSelected==false){

                  mPlayer.stop();
                  start.setText("Pause");
                  isSelected=true;
              }else{

                  start.setText("Pause"); 
                  isSelected=false;

                }
```

Answer (score 1):

you could just have 1 button which can handle different events and change its behaviour based upon the current button text.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getText()){
        case "Pause":
            mPlayer.stop();
            start.setText("Play");
        break;

        case "Play":
            start.setText("Pause");
            mPlayer.play();
        break; 
    }
}
```

or you could have the button initally setup to fire 1 click event which once fired then sets the button click event to the second click event and vice versa

```
public void onClickOne()
{
   // do stuff
   btn.OnClick = onClickTwo();
 }

public void onClickTwo()
{ 
    // do stuff
   btn.OnClick = onClickOne
}
```

Comment: gettext() is not accepting by eclipse it is giving error.

in first code

Comment: You can only `switch` on an `int` in the version of Java supported by Android. Also for this to work, you would have to cast `v` to a `Button` before trying to get the text.

Comment: yes i am already using v.gettext() but eclipse is not accepting it

Comment: Yes, because you aren't casting it to a `Button` first. This code won't work the way it is written for the two reasons I mentioned.

Comment: Yes, sorry this is more pseudo code then actual code. Example was more to give you the general idea.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing it in this way:

```
 String value=start.getText().toString();
 if(value.equals("Start")){
     start.setText("Pause");
 }
 else if(value.equals("Pause")){
     start.setText("Start");
 }
```